# Combining Multiple MySQL JOIN Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have this query which echos IDs of assignments for classes which users are enrolled in.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT assignments.*, enrollments.course_id, enrollments.student_id
                        FROM assignments
                        LEFT JOIN enrollments
                        ON assignments.course_id = enrollments.course_id
                        LEFT JOIN completed
                        ON assignments.id != completed.assignment_id
                        WHERE enrollments.student_id = ?
                        ORDER BY assignments.id DESC LIMIT 10
                        ");

$sql->execute(array($login_id));

while($row = $sql->fetch())
        {
                echo $row['id'];
        }
```

What would be the best way to do yet another check where I see if the assignment has been marked as completed?

This means that it would also need to check the "completed" table and make sure there is no row where the $login_id and assignment.id are present together for any of the assignments selected.

Here's a query I have right now to find completed assignment IDs for a user logged in.

```
$sqlcomplete = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM completed
INNER JOIN students ON completed.student_id = students.id
WHERE completed.student_id = ?
");

$sqlcomplete->execute(array($login_id));

while($row = $sqlcomplete->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo "<li>You have completed assignment with ID ".$row['assignment_id']."</li>";
}
```

I've tried to do a more complex `JOIN` but I can't seem to figure it out. I also considered simply creating an array of the IDs of the assignments which the user has completed by querying that database alone, and throwing that ID into the while check, but I feel like that is not the best or most efficient solution.

Comment: What's your table structure?

Comment: use a where condition and inner join

Comment: LEFT JOIN completed ON assignments.id != completed.assignment_id is going to give you a massive result set

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and when `completed.assignment_id IS NULL` then that means there was no match returned from the completed table.

```
SELECT assignments.*, enrollments.course_id, enrollments.student_id
FROM assignments
 LEFT JOIN enrollments ON assignments.course_id = enrollments.course_id
 LEFT JOIN completed ON assignments.id = completed.assignment_id
WHERE enrollments.student_id = ?
AND completed.assignment_id IS NULL
ORDER BY assignments.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: NULL is the answer, but why outer join?

Comment: actually, it doesn't need to be an outer join. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` mean the same. I prefer that syntax because for me it leaves out any confusion what I'm trying to do

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but this didn't seem to work for me. Check Mikhail's solution above.

Comment: i am not asking about syntax

Comment: Now that you've edited it, it works. Seems like the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` did make a difference? Thanks though!

Comment: @Peter if it's not an outer join then the `completed.assignment_id IS NULL` will never be true, unless he is joining `NULL` id's, but I highly doubt that.

Comment: heheheheh i am just trying to point you to answer - if you just want to check is null or not use inner join

Comment: no. you consider what is the point for outer join if you check it is NULL or not only..

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you're trying to say? How would you perform this query with a `NULL` condition? You have to have an `OUTER JOIN` to get `NULL` values on a join